# Get element from JSON and slice it

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've got this JSON array (mdataarray)

```
[
{
"frumain" : "ESC",
"fruother" : "PAC or SEP or SPCB",
"connector" : "SE3 or SE7",
"sensor" : "ECHC, ECPC, ECCC, PCEC",
"motorsolenoid" : "ESCM",
"causeoferror" : "004, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 210, 211, 212, 213, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 312"
}
]
```

And I need to get just "causeoferror" object and slice it where the commas but I don't get it.
I defined a new variable

```
public mdatacoe : string;
```

But when I do

```
this.mdatacoe = this.mdataarray.causeoferror;
```

In the console log I recieve undefined.

I'm pretty new to Typescript, I don't understand what I fail.

Comment: The array doesn't have that property, the object in it does. I'd strongly recommend reading up on basic JS.

Comment: Thanks, but which property?

Comment: What do you mean *"which property"*? The one you asked for, `causeoferror`. You should know it's an array, as *you included that in the name*.

Comment: @WilliamManzato You should be looking at `this.mdataarray[0].causeoferror` since the object is contained within an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your variable mdatacoe is of type string and not of type string[]:

I added a duplicate of the same json object into the array to mock multiple "causeoferror" properties.  The map operator accesses the "causeoferror" property and the join operator converts the array to a string.

```js
const foo = [
  {
    frumain: "ESC",
    fruother: "PAC or SEP or SPCB",
    connector: "SE3 or SE7",
    sensor: "ECHC, ECPC, ECCC, PCEC",
    motorsolenoid: "ESCM",
    causeoferror:
      "004, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 210, 211, 212, 213, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 312"
  },
  {
    frumain: "ESC",
    fruother: "PAC or SEP or SPCB",
    connector: "SE3 or SE7",
    sensor: "ECHC, ECPC, ECCC, PCEC",
    motorsolenoid: "ESCM",
    causeoferror:
      "004, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 210, 211, 212, 213, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 312"
  }
];

const bar = foo.map(x => x.causeoferror).join();

console.log(bar);
```

If you are indeed wanting an array of type string[], then @StepUp solution should be considered instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just take necessary object property of an array. Then you can split your string by comma sign ',':

```
const result = arr.map(({causeoferror}) => causeoferror.split(','));
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "frumain": "ESC",
        "fruother": "PAC or SEP or SPCB",
        "connector": "SE3 or SE7",
        "sensor": "ECHC, ECPC, ECCC, PCEC",
        "motorsolenoid": "ESCM",
        "causeoferror": "004, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 110, 111, 210, 211, 212, 213, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 312"
    }
];

const result = arr.map(({causeoferror}) => causeoferror.split(','));
console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array. change your code to this: `this.mdatacoe = this.mdataarray[0].causeoferror;`